# Getting a framework to deal with knockout.js not persisting via hidden field

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

- VS2013, WebForms, .NET 4.51

I want to use a hidden field to maintain the contents of my Knock Out view model across postbacks. So I took the KO code from http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html and then read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153735/Using-KnockoutJS-in-your-ASP-NET-applications for some ideas.

The end result is the following:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/sampleProductCategories.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatCurrency(value) {
        return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
    }

    var CartLine = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.category = ko.observable();
        self.product = ko.observable();
        self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
        self.subtotal = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.product() ? self.product().price * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0;
        });

        // Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
        self.category.subscribe(function () {
            self.product(undefined);
        });
    };

    var Cart = function () {
        // Stores an array of lines, and from these, can work out the grandTotal
        var self = this;
        self.lines = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default
        self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $.each(self.lines(), function () { total += this.subtotal() })
            return total;
        });

        // Operations
        self.addLine = function() {
            self.lines.push(new CartLine());
            SaveList();
        };
        self.removeLine = function(line) {
            self.lines.remove(line);
            SaveList();
        };
        self.save = function () {
            var dataToSave = $.map(self.lines(), function (line) {
                return line.product() ? {
                    productName: line.product().name,
                    quantity: line.quantity()
                } : undefined
            });
            alert("Could now send this to server: " + JSON.stringify(dataToSave));
        };

        self.SaveList = function () {
            var myHidden = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');

            if (myHidden)//checking whether it is found on DOM, but not necessary
            {
                var dataToSave = $.map(self.lines(), function (line) {
                    return line.product() ? {
                        productName: line.product().name,
                        quantity: line.quantity()
                    } : undefined;
                });
                alert("Saving - " + JSON.stringify(dataToSave));

                myHidden.value = JSON.stringify(dataToSave);
            }

        };
    };

    var stringViewModel = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value;
    var viewModel;

    if (document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value == '') {
        alert('Nothing In Hidden Field');
        viewModel = new Cart();
    } else {
        viewModel = ko.utils.parseJson(stringViewModel);
        for (var propertyName in viewModel) {
            viewModel[propertyName] = ko.observable(viewModel[propertyName]);
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $(document.forms[0]).submit(function () {
        alert('In Submit');
        viewModel.SaveList();
    });
</script>
```

So basically when the page loads we create a new instance of the Cart. And when the form is posted we successfully have the cart serialized to HiddenField1 and I can see the expected value in the code behind:

```
protected void btnSave_OnClick(object aSender, EventArgs aE)
{
    if (HiddenField1.Value == null)
    {

    }
}
```

however after the postback the contents of **stringViewModel**

```
var stringViewModel = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value;
```

is always blanl / empty? Why is that?

And then assuming I have the correct JSON is the following the correct way to apply it back to the view model?

```
viewModel = ko.utils.parseJson(stringViewModel);
for (var propertyName in viewModel) {
    viewModel[propertyName] = ko.observable(viewModel[propertyName]);
}
```

**EDIT: I tried a few things with no luck**

- Added all JS code to jQuert OnReady() handler
- Tried using  instead of ASP:HiddenField

In all cases in PostBack I can see the value assigned to the hidden field by SaveList(), but when the page is displayed again (after postback) the value of the hidden field is an empty string

Comment: can you post a fiddle at http://www.jsfiddle.com

Comment: @raheelshan I can't JsFiddle it as it involves ASP.NET not pure JavaScript and HTML. So it won't be representative. If you need more code then let me know and I will post what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, what you're doing is correct. Use the console (press F12 in your browser) to examine the hidden field, and check if it has the value. If you see it in the server side, it should be in the client side. You can also run js code, and set breakpoints to discover what the problem is. You can also add a PreRender handler in the server side, and add a breakpoint and debug to check that the Value has not been deleted in the server side (this event happens just before the page is rendered to be sent to the browser).

For the second part, the fastest way to do what you need is to use [knockout mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), which creates a model from a JavaScript object, or from JSON. You need to use this: `ko.mapping.fromJSON`. This will create a new viewmodel, which you can directly bind, from your JSON. (As you can read in the docs, you can customize how the view model is created).

However, what you're doing is quite strange. You normally use Knockout with Web API, or Web Services, or Page methods, without reloading the page. The model is recovered, and updated, changed, etc. through one of those technologies, using AJAX.

Comment: I realise this is an odd request, but I have a need to do it this way using WebForms due to other requirements

Comment: The field definitely has a value as I can see in OnPostback in btnSave_OnClick(). However when the JavaScript runs it is blank.... Maybe if I wrap that in OnReady()